# Python dbus bus.register_object source code/documentation

Tags: python, dbus

When using `python dbus`, I need now to use the low-level API mentioned in the [documentation](https://pydbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/legacydocs/tutorial.html#lower-level-api). (The situation is, when registering a new object, the bus name happens to already exist, and according to the above docs, "one cannot publish twice".) However, I cannot find the documentation, nor the source code for the above method. For an MWE, consider the following code:

```
    bussi = dbus.SystemBus()
    bussi.publish(
        "com.bus.name.that.already.exists",
        ("mycustomobject", MyCustomObject())
    )
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

How one would publish an object, assuming the service name already exists, and hence the above code does not work?
Here, "mycustomobject" is a string that is appended to the bus name
"com.bus.name.that.already.exists", thereby providing an object name
"/com/bus/name/that/already/exists/mycustomobject".

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be:

```py
bussi.register_object(object_path, MyCustomObject(), None)
```